# Match multiple cells over different sheets - how?

Tags: excel

How do I count how many times two cells (F4 and C4) in Sheet1 exist at the same time in one row in sheet "Destroyed"

Tried and compare with COUNTIF but then I just get the total number of times any of the values in F4 and C4 exist in the correct columns (B:B and N:N).

```
=COUNTIF(Destroyed!B:B;F4)+COUNTIF(Destroyed!N:N;C4)
```

Comment: By "At the same time", do you mean "in the same row"?  If so, look at `COUNTIFS`  (Adding is "or", not "and")

Comment: yes... "in the same row"

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIFS(Destroyed!B:B; F4, Destroyed!N:N; C4)
```

Counts the number of rows where Column B matches F4 **and** Column N matches C4

[Official Microsoft Office Support page for the `COUNTIFS` function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) - (note the subtle difference between `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS`)